# Cannot set focus on input field in infoWindow

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Why is focus not set to noteTitle?

I am using google maps API V3.

The getNoteForm() returns a input field "noteTitle".

The $("#noteTitle").focus() works fine when executed in firebug.

I call this function when clicking on the map:

```
function setNewNoteInfowindow(latlng) {
 if (geocoder) {
       geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
   var address = "";

     if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    if (results[1]) { 
     address =  results[1].formatted_address;
            }
         }

   newNoteInfowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: getNoteForm(latlng, address),
       size: new google.maps.Size(40,50)
   });

   newNoteInfowindow.open(map, newNoteMarker);

   google.maps.event.addListener(newNoteInfowindow, 'domready', function() {
          $("#noteTitle").focus();
      });

   google.maps.event.addListener(newNoteInfowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
          newNoteMarker.setVisible(false);
      });
  });
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried moving the `$("#noteTitle").focus();` statement elsewhere? Start with it in $(document).ready perhaps?

Comment: have you verified that the event is fired correctly ? add an `alert('something');` to see if it executes..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are opening your infowindow before adding the event listener. So the event has already been fired by the time you add the listener.  Try reversing the order of open() and addListener()

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(newNoteInfowindow, 'domready', function() {
          $("#noteTitle").focus();
      });

   newNoteInfowindow.open(map, newNoteMarker);
```

Comment: Solved it like this. Not pretty, but it works.
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
 placeNewNote(event.latLng);
 setTimeout(function(){$("#noteTitle").focus()}, 500);
});